# Training neural network with own dataset doesn't work due to cache strange problem

Tags: python, caching, neural-network, transformer-model, transfer-learning

I faced a strange challenge trying to train neural network using code from github, it is huggingface conversational model.

What happens: even i use my own dataset for training result remains the same like with original dataset. My hypothesis that it is a somehow cache problem - old dataset continuously get loaded from cached and replace my.
Them when i launch actual interactive session with neural network it works, but without my data, even if i pass model checkpoint.

Why i think of cache: in this repo author use automatic downloading and caching neural network model in /home/joo/.cache/torch/pytorch_transformers/ if no parameter specified in terminal.

*I have created an issue on Github. BUT i am not sure is that a problem specific for this repo only, or it is a common problem with retraining neural networks i faced first time.*

https://github.com/huggingface/transfer-learning-conv-ai/issues/36

Some copypaste from issue:

> I am still curious, was not able to pass my dataset:
>
> ```
> I added to original 200mb json my personality
> trained once more with --dataset_path ./my.json
> invoke interact.py with new checkpoint and path python ./interact.py --model_checkpoint
> ```
>
> ./runs/Oct08_18-22-53_joo-tf_openai-gpt/ --dataset_path ./my.json
>       and it reports Gathered 18878 personalities (but not 18879, with my own).
>       I changed the code in interact.py to choose my first perosnality this way
>
> was: personality = random.choice(personalities)
>
> become: personality = personalities[0]
>
> and this first personality is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: it is a specific issue to this repo, just hardcoded dataset path.
But still why it doesn't load first time - no answer